# Component loads in localhost but gives internal server error on live

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, ajax

I have a simple component with 1 php file that returns data from database. The file is called using JS AJAX from my homepage, and works perfectly when hosted locally.

But on deploying it to live server, the AJAX call returns with :

> failed to load resource. Internal server error occurred 500.

I have tried giving permissions and re configuring htaccess.txt file... but all vein..

example: localhost:1000/index.php?option=com_comp&option=raw --- works web.azurewebsites.net/index.php?option=com_comp&option=raw --- dosent work

Answer (score 2):

In the .htaccess file uncomment this line:

```
#RewriteBase /
```

Make it :

```
RewriteBase /
```

It have worked for me before on the same error

Comment: thank you for your quick response..but unfortunately..its still not working...the error says : The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.